# change attribute of a selected element value dynamically from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have two elements inside a parent container.

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid" myvalue="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" id="secid" myvalue="2"></div>
```

Now I select firstitem, I set the value from spinner and code will be something like selectable plugin but I want to assign values to selected item.

```
  $('#myspinner').spinner({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //change myid myvalue to selected value
        }
    });
```

How can I change the value of the second element using the same code?
My fiddle [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/learningweb/g524X/5/)

Comment: How do you get selected value here? Is it coming from the `event` or `ui` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid" myvalue="1"></div>
<div class="myclass" id="secid" myvalue="2"></div>

var spinner = $("#spinner").spinner();
    var selectedDiv = '';

    $('.myclass').click(function () {
        selectedDiv = this;
    });

    $('#myspinner').spinner({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(selectedDiv).html(this.value);
        }
    });
```

The `selectedDiv` variable will hold the element that has been selected by clicking. When the spinner is stopped, the `stop:` function is triggered. This will in turn set the html content of the selected div to the value selected using the spinner (`this.value`)

Comment: Can you tell us what this does?

Comment: When the element with id myid is clicked, its value is changed to the value of element with id myspinner, which is the element on which the jQuery spinner is added to.

Comment: thats not wat i mean nikh. your way is reverse as mine.i wan to click the div first and change the value from spinner.i click on next div and change the value from the spinner again on selected div only

Comment: Check my edited answer and see if it works for you. You need to focus on the `$('#myspinner').spinner('value')` part since that will give you the selected value from the spinner. You can assign it to the element you wish to.

Comment: I think I know what you're doing now. This spinner of yours is doing some type of spinning and when it stops, "maybe from the user stopping it by clicking on it while it is spinning", triggers the stop event. So, #Nikhil has it right. You'll have to look at the spinner documentation in order to know how to retrieve the value of the selected spinner value. I bet you could set the value like  $("#myid").val(this.value); or $("#myid").val(ui.value);

Comment: i can retrive thevalue of spinner during stop event. how do i set the value to the div upon selecting the div first and change the value in div.
nik suggested is change the value in spinner first and select a div

i update a link to fiddle

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g524X/3/. Try this: Click a div, change the spinner value. Your div text will change to the value selected from the spinner.

Comment: To be cleaner you can set the value of the div like so,   $(selectedDiv).html(this.value);

Comment: Nikhil thank so much. finally u guys understand my requirement
mind if you change your code here and i can mark as answered?

Comment: edited the answer as per the fiddle and suggestions by @AlumCloud.Com

Comment: Add an explanation please.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is incorrect. You might want to check it out and re-post it.

If you want a click event to happen when `firstitem` is clicked then your selector should be `$('.firstitem')` and not `$('#myspinner')`.

You'll need to make those changes to begin with.

Comment: i just wrote it here and didnt test it out